# CentOS 6.6 x64 - cPanel 11.46.2 - Git not updating, Stuck on 1.7.1

Tags: linux, git, centos, cpanel, yum

I am not sure why, but last night I ran "yum install git". Apparently my server already had (or should have had) git installed. According to the changelog, cPanel/WHM 11.46.2 should come with Git 2.2.0: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/11.46+Change+Log

My installed git version is 1.7.1 !!!

'yum update git' reports there is nothing to do.

'yum remove git' then 'yum update' then 'yum install git', installs again 1.7.1! What gives!

Why does my server not grab the 2.2.0 that my cpanel version ships with? How can I reset this, or use, the one my server is supposed to use? For all I know, it could have had the 2.2.0 version, then me doing 'yum install git' could have messed it up?

I don't really want to download a tar, extract, and install the source manually. I shouldn't have to, I should be able to "yum install git" and get the version my cpanel comes with.

In WHM I updated RPM database.. still no go..

I got my bare repo on my cpanel bare-metal server, and can "git push" to it. The problem I have is I get a 500 internal server error after the first checkout, which puts all the files in my public_html through the post-receive hook. I edited 'index.php' just by 1 edit, saved it, and the error is gone and the site operates as normal. I don't know why I am getting an internal error, maybe a bug with this old Git version when checking out from the bare repo?

I always have this issue with yum, it never has or installs the version it's supposed to for my cpanel version.

I have spent a few hours on this already, and hoping someone can guide me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: git 1.7.1 is the latest version officially packaged for CentOS 6.

Comment: Then I am confused why cpanel doc says 2.2.0, or even includes git...

How can I update my CentOS to 'yum install git' and have it use 2.2.0 or later?

Comment: @WadeShuler, it may be installed to a different location. `yum remove git`, then see if you can still run `git`.

Comment: I have no idea what on earth those changelogs are talking about. I suppose it could be some bundled cPanel product. You don't, as far as I know, get yum to install a git that new on CentOS 6. You can look for third-party repositories that might have it though.

Comment: No need to remove `git` to test that. Just see what `type -a git` says. Though it won't list anything not in the current `$PATH` and it is entirely likely that if `cPanel` installed its own `git` they did so in a non-standard location.

Comment: @EtanReisner cpanel puts git in: /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/git

cd to that folder, and git --version reports 1.7.1. I did a force re-install of cpanel from inside WHM. Appears its not the version their site claims it should be!

I dabble in this, and am no expert with linux or centos and repos. I can navigate linux, familiar with its commands, etc. Beyond that, is unfamiliar territory.

So I guess I need to know how to find, and use, the correct RPM to install the latest git version.

Comment: `git` will use the version in the `$PATH` no matter where you are currently. Use `./git` to use the version in the current directory or a full path.

Comment: @EtanReisner Both report the same version: `./usr/bin/git --version` returns **git version 1.7.1**  and  `git --version` returns **git version 1.7.1**

Comment: @EtanReisner Found updated git on server (2.2.0) in `root@build01 [/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin]# ./git --version`. So how do I use this copy of git and get rid of the other 1.7.1 versions. Can I update this 2.2.0 located in `/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin` to 2.2.1 or whatever is the latest stable version?

Comment: I think I got it, at least good enough. Creating a symlink will override the CentOS git: `ln -sf /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/git /usr/local/bin/git`. git was already located in /usr/local/bin so I was confused, but the symlink takes precedence here.

Comment: What git was already in `/usr/local/bin`? And I would assume cPanel will use its git even if the system has one. So the only issue was if *you* wanted to use the cPanel git instead of the system one but sure.

Comment: That Git version was 1.7.1 but the git in the cpanel 3rdparty directory was 2.2.0. I didn't find any symlinks (so I could remove it) and created a symlink to cpanel's git. So my git on the server is now using the cpanel's version 2.2.0.
 
I got it all sorted out. I just wish someone would post an answer so I can mark it. I can't post answers right now, or I would answer it myself. I could use the points to get my account going. I got down voted answering some guys question and can't post answers now :(